# Best way to avoid if statements with logic in Javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

What's the best way in JavaScript to avoid conditional branching like this:

```
if(a && b) return doW();
if (a && !b) return doX();
if(!a && b) return doY();
if(!a && !b) return doZ();
```

Comment: I suppose rather than avoid I mean what would be another way of approaching it without using conditional branching?

Comment: Without branching you can't do what you want to do (because you can't `jump`).  What *particular* constructs are you trying to avoid?

Comment: There can be a near infinite number of "correct" answers to this question and thus it is off-topic according to the [help/on-topic].

Comment: underscore.js gives you a lot of functions that help you to avoid too much branching, especially if it comes to arrays. I am trying to think of a solution where your functions would be picked from an array based on the boolean values.

Comment: It is too bad that this was put on hold. However, you should never asked a question with 'best way' than everyone will jump on you. Reformulate, like how can I do this without if statement or something.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different (but equivalent) structure may be more readable, depending on what a/b actually are. You can avoid branching flatly over all combinations of `a` and `b` with some nesting:

```
if (a) {
  return b ? doW() : doX();
}
else {
  return b ? doY() : doZ();
}
```

or:

```
if (a) {
  if (b) doW();
  else doX();
}
else {
  if (b) doY();
  else doZ();
}
```

I think conditional logic is ideal here, so there's no need to avoid `if/else` logic. However if you really are interested in a way, here's an interesting solution using a map:

```
var map = {
  true: {
    true: doW,
    false: doX
  },
  false: {
    true: doY,
    false: doZ
  }
}

map[a][b]();
```

Comment: You can drop those ifs/elses as well and go full-ternary. Not sure it would be readable to someone not used to it. What you did looks just about right for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object literal to store your functions,.

```js
function doW() {
  console.log('do W');
}
function doX() {
  console.log('do X');
}
function doY() {
  console.log('do Y');
}
function doZ() {
  console.log('do Z');
}


var fn = {
  '11': doW,
  '10': doX,
  '01': doY,
  '00': doZ
}
  
function doFn(a, b) {
  fn[(a|0)+''+(b|0)+'']();
}

doFn(false, true);
```